# Absolute position divs not vertically spaced evenly

Tags: html, css, sass

The absolute positioned divs aren't spaced evenly. I checked the calc over and over again but I can't find anything wrong with the math. I know you can do this with flexbox but I need to do this with absolute positioning.

HTML:

```
<section class="book">

            <div class="book__side-edit book__side-edit--1" alt="Burger"></div>
            <div class="book__side-edit book__side-edit--2" alt="Burger"></div>
            <div class="book__side-edit book__side-edit--3" alt="Burger"></div>

        </section>
```

CSS

```
.book{
    height: 95.625vh;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    &__side-edit{
        height: 177px;
        width: 177px;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: blue;

        &--1{
            top: calc( (95.625vh - (177px * 3)) / 3);
            left: 0;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
        }

        &--2{
            top: calc( ( (95.625vh - (177px * 3)) / 3 ) * 2);
            right: 0;
            transform: translateX(50%);
        }

        &--3{
            top: calc( ( (95.625vh - (177px * 3)) / 3 ) * 3);
            left: 0;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please tag the CSS preprocessor you're using.

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want all the .book__side-edit divs to be vertically spaced evenly in the .book div

Comment: then why one div has `right : 0`

Comment: I want that div to be on the right side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add the already existing .side-edit heights. The second one needs to have `+ 177px` and the third one needs `+ 354px` ( or 2 * 177px );

I added a 531px min-height to the book in the snippet to ensure space for all 3 177px boxes and I removed the translate style to concentrate on top and height. Because of this I'm using 100% within the calculations but I think it's cleaner this way even if you don't end up dealing with the min-height issue.

```css
/* 177px * 3 = 531px */

.book {
  height: 95.625vh;
  min-height: 531px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.book__side-edit {
  height: 177px;
  width: 177px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
}



.book__side-edit--1 {
  top: calc( (100% - 531px) * 1 / 3);
  left: 0;
}

.book__side-edit--2 {
  top: calc( (100% - 531px) * 2 / 3 + ( 177px * 1 ) );
  right: 0;
}

.book__side-edit--3 {
  top: calc( (100% - 531px) * 3 / 3 + ( 177px * 2 ) );
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="book">

  <div class="book__side-edit book__side-edit--1" alt="Burger"></div>
  <div class="book__side-edit book__side-edit--2" alt="Burger"></div>
  <div class="book__side-edit book__side-edit--3" alt="Burger"></div>

</section>
```

Comment: The last div at the bottom doesn't have the same space and the div at the top does. I was looking for a way to make the bottom div have the same space at the bottom as the top div has on the top.

Comment: Nevermind I solved it by dividing it by 4 instead of 3 thank you!